# While condition

Tags: algorithm

I have the following code:

```
While[Total[{0,1,3}] != 2, 
 {0,1,3} -(#[[Ordering[Max[] & /@ #]]])]
```

I want to decrease the maximum coefficient of the vector until the total is equal to my condition.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: The While gate never changes. You're asking it to recompute the same expression (`Total[{0,1,3}]`) at the start of each iteration; this will always give `4`, no matter what. You should use a variable to store the list `{0, 1, 3}` and then manipulate that variable in the body of the While loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for, but here's my best guess.

I'm taking `v` to be a vector of random integers between 1 and 10, but you could use your `{0, 1, 3}` vector, or any other vector of integers. (Make sure that `v` is initialized so that `Total[v] >= 2`, otherwise it'll never terminate.) The `While` condition checks whether `Total[v]` is equal to 2. If it's not, it reduces the maximal integer in `v` by 1.

```
SeedRandom[1]; v = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 3]
While[Total[v] != 2,
 v[[First@Ordering[v, -1]]]--
 ];
v

(* {2, 5, 1} *)
(* {1, 1, 0} *)
```

One thing to watch with this approach, however, is that if `v` contains two maximal entries `Ordering[v, -1]` will always give the position of the last one. That means the last maximal entry will always be the one that gets reduced, and so you'll always end up with an output of `{1, 1, 0}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what i want

Comment: @Hugobine Glad to help. You can click on the tick to properly accept the answer.